# How to use httpie and jq within docker?

Tags: docker, jq, httpie

How to use httpid and jq within docker?

I want to get the ip only in json result like '34.10.12.40'

```shell
docker run -it --rm blacktop/httpie -b ifconfig.co/json
{
    "country": "United States",
    "country_eu": false,
    "country_iso": "US",
    "hostname": "lqwtx.com",
    "ip": "34.10.12.40",
    "ip_decimal": 39585,
    "latitude": 35,
    "longitude": 105
}
```

but I've tried some ways but does not work, like blow.

```shell
docker run -it --rm blacktop/httpie ash -c "http -b ifconfig.co/json | jq '.ip’”

docker run -it --rm blacktop/httpie -b ifconfig.co/json jq '.ip'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the dockerfile of the image you used, see [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/blacktop/httpie/dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache jq httpie

ENTRYPOINT [ "http" ]
CMD [ "--help" ]
```

From above, you can see it set an `entrypoint` with `http` for this image, so all your command used in `docker run` will be act as parameters for `http`, so of course you will fail.

Next is a method for you to make use of it:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint=/bin/sh blacktop/httpie -c "http -b ifconfig.co/json | jq '.ip'"
```

Sample output:

```
"92.121.64.197"
```

Above command will override the default `entrypoint` with `/bin/sh`, then you can use `jq` to parse output of `httpie` in pipeline.